# Can not right redirect and make controller in controller in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller

I have two old controllers written in Jersey. I need to rewrite them in Spring Boot, but unfortunately not a single guide gave the answer to me to do it as efficiently as possible.

return "redirect..." does not suit me because in the second controller there are a lot of methods and there is a param idr which is unique with each request

1.Method in first controller

```
@Path("{id}/second")
public SecondEndpoint getSecondEndpoint(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return this.beanFactory
            .getBean(SecondEndpoint.class, id);
}
```

2. Second Controller

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class SecondEndpoint {

    private final Long id;

    @GET
    @Path("{secondId}")
    public String saySmth((@PathParam("secondId") Long secondId){
       return "hello" + id + " " + secondId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Arseny you want to write above in Spring boot?

Comment: Hello @PatelRomil !
No. I want to rewrite from Jersey to Spring

Answer (score 0):

try the below one

```
@RestController 
ClassRoot {

@Autowired
private SecondEndpoint secondEndPoint; // Autowire to inject SecondEndpoint instance 

  @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE ,path = "id")
public SecondEndpoint getSecondEndpoint(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return secondEndPoint.saySmth(id);
}
}


@Service
public class SecondEndpoint {

    private final Long id;

    public String saySmth((@PathParam("secondId") Long secondId){
       return "hello" + id + " " + secondId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have two problems.

1. I should not use jersey due to the nature of testing
2. In Second Class, there are a lot of methods and I want FirstClass to be a provider and send the methods to SecondClass for execution.

For example, when I followed the path '/ 0 / second / 1', I first got into the method from FirstClass, it created an instance of SecondsClass with the specified variable as a field and then delegated control to the second class

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AssenKhan , but there are a lot of methods in SecondClass and I don’t really want to write a separate method on FirstClass for each method of SecondClass